# RequireJS noUiSlider is not defined

Tags: requirejs, nouislider

I got problem with https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider

Use requireJS, config.js and build.js

```
 paths: {
    nouislider: '../core/lib/nouislider/nouislider',
  },
  shim: {
    nouislider: {
      deps: ['jquery'],
      exports: '$'
    },
  },
```

script:

```
require(['jquery', 'nouislider'], function ($) {
"use strict";
  $(function () {
    var range = document.getElementById('range');
    range.style.height = '400px';
    range.style.margin = '0 auto 30px';
    noUiSlider.create(range, {
      connect: true,
      behaviour: 'tap',
      start: [ 500, 4000 ],
      range: {
        // Starting at 500, step the value by 500,
        // until 4000 is reached. From there, step by 1000.
        'min': [ 0 ],
        '10%': [ 500, 500 ],
        '50%': [ 4000, 1000 ],
        'max': [ 10000 ]
      }
    });
  });
});
```

On my web I have this error ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined

Anyone have the same problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require it like this:

```
require(['jquery', 'nouislider'], function ($, noUiSlider) {
```

I've just added the last parameter to the callback. If you look at its source code, you'll see that it detects whether an AMD loader is present (checks that `define` is a function and has the property `amd` on it) and if so it calls `define`. So you have to use the module's value like I show above, rather than rely on `noUiSlider` being present in the global space.

By the way, setting a `shim` for code that calls `define` is completely useless. `shim` is only for code that does not use `define`. So you should remove the `shim` you show in the question.